# Why does Identity operator work in general in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

As much as I could understand from reading quantum mechanics-related texts, the identity operator works on a state vector as follows

\begin{align}
|\Psi\rangle&=\sum_{n} c_n |n \rangle \\
\sum_m|m\rangle\langle m|\Psi \rangle&=\sum_m\sum_nc_n\langle m|n\rangle |m\rangle\\
&=\sum_m\sum_nc_n\delta_{mn}|m\rangle\\
&=\sum_nc_n|n\rangle
\end{align}
Basically, the operation is dependent upon the fact that we write $|\Psi\rangle$ as $\sum_n c_n |n \rangle$.
Now suppose I do $A$ operation on $|\Psi\rangle$
\begin{align}
A|\Psi\rangle&=\sum_{n} c_n A|n \rangle \tag{1} \\
\sum_m|m\rangle\langle m|A|\Psi \rangle&=\sum_m\sum_nc_n\langle m|A|n\rangle |m\rangle
\end{align}
My question is how do we get back (1)? I understand that if $A|\Psi\rangle=a|\Psi\rangle$ I can get back (1). But is it necessary that each operator have an eigenvalue?

Comment: Just reverse the step in your last equality, i.e. swap $\langle m|A|n\rangle$ with $|m\rangle$?! What is the problem?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker The problem was that I was unable to show $\sum_m\sum_n c_n\langle m|A|n \rangle|m\rangle=\sum_n c_nA|n\rangle$. I now understood that I had missed the point that the basis is complete. Though I am not able to understand what you intend to do by swapping.

Comment: I mean $\langle m|A|n\rangle |m\rangle =  |m\rangle \langle m|A|n\rangle$, just what you've used in the very same equality...Then the desired result is easy to see, by summing over $m$.

Comment: I am trying to prove that summing over $m$ works like an identity operator in the case when it is operating on $A|\Psi\rangle$. For that I am trying to show that $\sum_m |m\rangle \langle m|A|\Psi\rangle=A|\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: I really don't understand, sorry. But as it seems, you got a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the set of states $\{\left | n \right>\}$ forms a complete basis, you can always write $A\left | n \right>=\sum_kc'_k\left | k \right>$ for some coefficients $c'_k$. If you plug this into your equation for $A\left | \Psi \right>$ you should be able to get the answer.

Alternatively, you cay simply say directly that $A\left | \Psi \right>=\left | \phi \right>$, where $\left | \phi \right>$ is some state and hence can be written as $\left | \phi \right>=\sum_j c''_j\left | j \right>$ for some coefficients $c''_j$ and the the result follows as in your first calculation.