# What does the identity operator mean in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I'm new to quantum mechanics, and I am beginning to study Dirac notation, but I do not understand the significance or meaning of the following equation:

$$\sum_n\left|e_n\right\rangle\left\langle e_n\right|=1$$

or for that matter, this equation as well:

$$\int\left|e_z\right\rangle\left\langle e_z\right| d z=1$$

But I do understand that:

$$\hat{P} \equiv \left|\alpha\right\rangle\left\langle \alpha\right|$$

is an operator that can find the projection of a vector, say $|\beta\rangle$, along the direction of $|\alpha\rangle$

Apologies if I similar question has been asked before, but I was not able to find one that directly answered my question.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? Do you know what orthonormal bases are and that you can expand every vector in such a basis? If yes, just apply the LHS to a vector and see what comes out, then compare it with the identity operator applied to the same vector. If not, read about ONBs.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I don't understand the first equation I listed at all really, I read it as the sum of the inner products of every basis vector with itself in a vector space as being equal to one, but it makes no sense to me since an orthonormal vector has has a value of one when the inner product with itself is taken

Comment: for example if a vector space had 3 basis vectors, all of which were orthonormal, wouldn't the first equation be equal to 3?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you try what I've suggested in my comment? Note also that on the LHS there is no inner product and on the RHS the $1$ is meant to be the identity operator, not a number (which will become also clear if you do this simple exercise).

Comment: Why did you trace your 3x3 identity matrix? This is linear algebra, not QM…

Comment: For instance. in $\mathbb{C}^3$ with the usual basis $\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$ then $(1 0 0)^T(1 0 0) + (0 1 0)^T (0 1 0) + (0 0 1)^T (0 0 1)$ is just the 3x3 identity matrix

Comment: Is this of any help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714412/226902

Comment: ahh thank you @TobiasFünke I did what you suggested and I understand what the equation is saying now. It seems to me now that this equation is of little significance, am I right? I do however have a general question regarding the commutative properties in Dirac notation, when am I to know when it is permittable to change the order of the bra's and ket's?

Comment: @cookiecainsy The identity operator or completeness relation is probably one of most important and useful equations in QM. You will use it in formal calculation over and over and over again, sometimes twice or more times in the same equation.  When you get to graduate QM it will be your bread and butter. Don't forget it!

Comment: The level of significance you want to attribute to this equation is up to you; but yes, it is just the basis expansion in disguise... You should ask a separate, new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation
$$\sum_n|e_n\rangle\langle e_n|=1$$
is an operator equation. That means
$$\sum_n|e_n\rangle\langle e_n|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$$
is true for *every* vector $|\psi\rangle$.

As you know, in the sum on the left side every term
$|e_n\rangle\langle e_n|\psi\rangle$ is the projection
of $|\psi\rangle$ along the direction of $|e_n\rangle$.
So the equation says that the sum of all these projections
completely recovers the vector $|\psi\rangle$
(hence the name "completeness relation").

Or in other words: There is no part of $|\psi\rangle$ missing,
because the vectors $|e_n\rangle$ cover *all* possible
directions of the Hilbert space.